# Updated my Android Studio from 3.4.2 to 4.0,but unable to sync project due to missing of SDK 29(I have downloaded)

Tags: android-studio

Error:

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:androidApis'.
 Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-mockable-jar, 
 org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, returnDefaultValues=false}.
Execution failed for MockableJarTransform: C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android- 
 29\android.jar.
Cannot create mockable android.jar
C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-29\android.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Build.gradle

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
    dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
   }
  }

 allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

  task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Distribution Url

```
 https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

I have tried installing and Uninstalling SDK 29 and Tools ,but same error exists.

Please Help.